# Form still submitting after return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added validation but the form still submits even after the script has returned false

Form Submit

```
 <form action=payment.php method=POST name=UserForm id=UserForm onsubmit="return check(this);return false;">
```

Javascript

```
 function check(event) {    

 $('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
        alert('Some fields are empty');
       return false;
    }
   });  


   }
```

Comment: That second return false can NEVER be reached.

Comment: How could `return false;` ever be executed after another `return`?

Comment: You are not returning false from check() method. `return false` inside each loop is equivalent to `break;` statement

Comment: This doesn't explain the reason why he has this problem though.

Comment: @tenub sure it does. It explains why the form submits, which is due to not preventing it from submitting.

Comment: No it doesn't. The check function should be returning either true or false (which is what he was attempting to code), therefore making the extra return inaccessible and completely meaningless. See the posted answers for proper check functions.

Comment: @ChrisCampbell - You have asked several questions on this site, but haven't accepted any of the answers.  Please review the questions you've already asked, and accept the best answer for each of them by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`return false;` inside jQuery `each` won't work. You are returning inside an anonymous function, not inside `function check(event)`.
What you need to do is use a flag.

```
function check(event) {  
    var errorFlag = false;
    $('input').each(function() {

        if(!$(this).val()){
            alert('Some fields are empty');
            errorFlag = true;
        }

    }); 

    return !errorFlag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return check(this);return false;`

The second return `return false` is unreachable. Also, the alert statement blocks the return in your other code - and the `check` function doesn't return anything.

```
function check(event) {    
 $('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
       alert('Some fields are empty'); //blocking here
       return false; // this isn't the return of the check function
    }
   });  
}
```

You should do something like

```
function check(event) {    
   var result = true;
   $('input').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).val()){
       result = false;
    }
   });  

   return result;
}
```